# Google account sign-in requires a phone number to continue

Tags: gmail, google-account

When I sign in a new Google Account, this message shows:

> We've detected unusual activity on the account you're trying to access. To continue, please follow the instructions below.
>
> Provide a phone number to continue. We'll send a verification code you can use to sign in.

How can I avoid this message? I have no phone number.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid this message. This is for security check and you have to pass it. They have detected some suspicious activity on your account and that's why they are asking for verification.

If you don't have mobile number, you can use anyone's mobile number (friends or family phone number, always use trusted person mobile number) to get verification code. Once you logged in successfully. You can delete or change that number later from settings.